# "It was him the sea monster!" - Some kid at the end of the movie where a monster hides under human form

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for help to try to identify this movie I've been searching about for a while.

**When I saw it and additional infos :**

I saw it as a young kid in the 90's (I was born in 1993), I'd say possibly around 1998 with +/- 2 years without having any mean to identify an approximate release date.

It wasn't a black and white movie. I don't exclude it was a television one or a series episode and I saw it in my country (France) and in French.

Even if some parts were slightly scary for the kid I was, I'd say it was probably suitable for children.

**About the plot :**

There's a monster (probably a "sea" monster) hiding among people under human form.
From what I recall (and I could have mistaken some things as I was very young) he lived as the chief of a circus, main character was a kid, probably a boy. I don't recall if the monster was hiding as a woman or a man.

**About a few scenes I recall :**

- The monster is seen from behind arriving somewhere under human form. He talks to someone before entering and at that moment there's an eye opening in his back, only visible from the spectator.
- A plate with a cloche is put on a table (in front of the monster in disguise?). The cloche is removed and reveals a fish with a human face (man turned into fish by the monster?), alive and looking like a suffocating fish. Its color was pale blue if I recall correctly.

  NB: As I was searching I found out about Naso/unicorn fish, it reminds me of it a bit.
  [image: two blue unicorn fish on a light blue background]
- In the end, as the monster's non-human form is revealed and the water engulfs him, the main character says as he understands its true nature : "C'était lui le monstre des mers !" ("It was him the sea monster!"). In that scene, the monster is below and the humans are looking at him from above, out of water.

---

**Edit** : Possible answers excluded so far (work in progress) :

- Goosebumps :

  - [s01e04 : "The girl who cried monster"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aG-l6p8z6CE)

Comment: For some reasons, it reminds me of the kind of story you could watch in _[Are You Afraid of the Dark?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Are_You_Afraid_of_the_Dark%3F)_ (also called _[Fais-moi peur !](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fais-moi_peur_!)_ in French)

Comment: @Clockwork Thank you, I'll search through those episodes (as well as [Goosebumbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goosebumps_(1995_TV_series))) as I never considered it could come from there. I'll also update my answer accordingly .